# php search for dir and echo if exists or not

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a editbox and a submit button.
when someone types something in the editbox, lets say 'hello', the form would then search a directory on the server and echo the result on the page (below the editbox) like this - this directory exists 'or' this directory does not exist

Hope someone can help, any help is very appreciated.

```
<?php
$dir = 'hello';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
echo "The folder $dir exists";
} else {
echo "The folder $dir does not exist";
}
?>
```

The above code echo's if the directory 'hello' exists or not, this works fine, I just need it to read from another directory on the server and also from a form, I'm not sure what to place in the 'action' part of the php form for it to recognise and display the query.

Cheers,

Comment: Search on the entire server?

Comment: Hi, I have a directory called 'web' in the root with the other directory's inside, I need to search for the directory names in the 'web' directory (if that makes sense)

Comment: So what have you tried so far, show your code, in your question

Comment: I'll put it up later, I'm not at my computer at the moment, I'll do it asap :)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the above post with some code I have.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Thanks but I still need help :(

Answer (score 0):

If your form does a GET request, you can access the value from the `$_GET` variable.
If you need to check existence of a folder in another folder, you just need to create a string, that points to that folder.

```
<form>
    <input name="dir"/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['dir'])) // check if value is actually sent
    {
        $dir = $_GET['dir']; // retrieve the value
        if (is_dir('some_folder/'.$dir)) {
            echo "The folder $dir exists";
        } else {
            echo "The folder $dir does not exist";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi gre_gor, that is exactly what I was looking for thank you! I just need it now to search in a specific directory. The folder I have the above script in is root/web/my/index.php and the folder I need to look in is root/hello/

Comment: @ScottPaffley just replace `some_folder/` with `/root/hello/`

Comment: Hi gre_gor, I tried that but it always says the folder does not exist. :( I even tried the full url for the folder to look in.

Comment: Probably your web server has no `x` permission on `/root` folder. Do you really need those folder inside root folder?

Comment: it happens no matter which folder I place it in :(

Comment: I still think it's a permission problem. I got that code working on my server, with `some_folder` being in the same folder as the PHP file.